# How to use REPLACE with WhereRaw eloquent laravel?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, replace, where-clause

I have a column in my database that saved with double quotation (")
now I want to replace it by space.I'm using REPLACE and whereRaw.but It dosent work.
this is my code:

```
 $query->whereRaw("trim(REPLACE(name),'\"','') ='.trim($name).'")
```

actually using / for scaping (").Any Idea?

Comment: do you know howto do it in pure sql?

Comment: I guess you have a typo. **espace** or **space**?

Comment: @GiacomoM  Actually I want to do it in my laravel project.why pure sql?

Comment: @BABAKASHRAFIyah.sorry.Its space.:)))))

Comment: if you write in pure sql we can see what is wrong with php and laravel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you found the answer in the comments another thing what I suggest is don't append the value directly since this may lead to sql injection what I suggest you to use in `?` operator something like this

```
$query->whereRaw("trim(REPLACE(name),'\"','') = ? ",[trim($name)])
```